# Settings.py not working as expected Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Good evening, I am facing a weird problem with my django project. From my Ubuntu, where I started to develop it, I didn't find any issue around it, but when I tried to move it in my OS X El Capitan, then I'm either receiving one of this error:

1) When `APP_DIRS` is set to `True`: `app_dirs` must not be set when loaders is defined.

2) When `APP_DIRS` is set to `False` or removed: No module named 'admin_tools.template_loaders'

Is there anything that I'm doing bad in this settings.py?

That's how my settings.py looks like:

```
SITE_ID = 1

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',
    'tinymce',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'management',
    'myApp',
    'easy_thumbnails',

)


TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undp_redo_levels': 10,
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors',

            ],
            'loaders': [
                ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                ]),
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
        ]
        },

    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'management.IfasicUser'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_URL = 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)


CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> When `App_DIRS` is set to `True`: `app_dirs` must not be set when loaders is defined.

As the error says, you must remove the `app_dirs` setting when you define `loaders`.

> When `APP_DIRS` is set to `False` or removed: No module named 'admin_tools.template_loaders'

Try upgrading to 0.7.1, which was released today. Looking at [the changelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admin-tools), there appears to be a bug with the cached template loader.

Comment: I do have this is my pip freeze list: Django==1.8.6
django-admin-tools==0.6.0
django-crispy-forms==1.5.2
django-debug-toolbar==1.4
django-tinymce==2.0.6
easy-thumbnails==2.2.1
hgtools==6.3
Pillow==3.0.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
sqlparse==0.1.18
wheel==0.24.0

Comment: Try upgrading django-admin-tools to 0.7.1.

Comment: In that case I would try removing the cached template loader and using the file system and app directory loaders instead, to see whether 0.7.1 has really fixed the problem.

Comment: Disable the cached template loader by replacing `('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [...]),` with `'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader', 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',`. If that works, then it looks like 0.7.1 hasn't fixed the bug with the cached loader.